# Rotate drawable/gradient

Tags: android, xml, drawable

I'm trying to make a simple linear gradient. The trouble is, unless I use 0, 45, 90, 135 etc.. multiples of 45 for the angle value, the app crashes with an exception "Drawable not found". I need to rotate the gradient by 20 degrees. I tried to add *rotate* tag, which partially worked:

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <rotate android:fromDegrees="20" android:toDegrees="20">
            <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle" >
                <gradient
                    android:type="linear"
                    android:startColor="#112233"
                    android:centerColor="#667788"
                    android:endColor="#112233"
                    android:centerX="50%"
                    android:angle="0"/>
            </shape>
        </rotate>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

but produced the following result:

[image]

Is it possible to somehow "rotate" the gradient or is writing custom view the only option? Thanks!

Comment: You can give only multiples of 45 in angle attribute, other than that it crashes i.e 10, 20,50, etc. The default value is 0.